# Issues in compiling a mex file

Tags: matlab, mex

I am having some issues in compiling using mex this software http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~aspremon/ZIP/COVSEL.zip. When I use mex and give it the files to compile it shows the following error

```
error: 'CblasColMajor' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I am compiling the mex file from matlab and in Mac LionOS. Any suggestions

I am using the following code to compile

```
mex BoxQP.c BoxQP_mex.c utils.c
```

Comment: `CblasColMajor` is declared in an enum in the header file, but only if compiling for win32. I believe the code expects it to have been already declared in another header if you are compiling on mac.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `MACVERSION` macro is defined, or define it yourself.  It looks like the `CblasColMajor` enum is defined in the cblas.h file which is included on line 18 of BoxQP.h.  So I'm guessing that you either need to install the cblas library or it's there by default on OSX.  Here's what I had to use to compile it on Win32:

```
mex -v -g BoxQP_mex.c BoxQP.c utils.c -LC:\MATLAB\R2009bSP1\extern\lib\win32\microsoft -lmwblas
```

HTH, might want to include the line you're using to compile it if you can't figure it out.

*EDIT*

You'll need to find the library path for the Matlab install and then under that directory you'll need to look for `extern\lib\` then look for your platform and library type like, `extern\lib\linux\maxos` I'm not sure what it will look like, but that's a guess. also, include the Mathworks BLAS library using, `-lmwblas`.

Comment: I have compiled the cblass library and places the cblass_LINUX.a library package to /usr/loca/lib. What else do I need to do?

Comment: I could move a step ahead after defining MACVERSION. However, I have the following error.Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cblas_daxpy", referenced from _BoxQP in BoxQP.o